# Is there a way to force AKS to configure kubelet to use HTTPS for its metric endpoint?

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, kubelet

Is there a way to force AKS to configure kubelet to use HTTPS for its metric endpoint?

I currently have one cluster that has kubelet with http and another cluster with https. I can’t figure out what caused this.

I provisioned those two using terraform.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this post.

https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1087

The main reason is when you enable AAD on the cluster they open the https port.

https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1087#issuecomment-663693457

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, the cluster that has https does not use RBAC and AAD.

And the cluster with AAD and RBAC uses HTTP...

Comment: I added more details to the GitHub issue, I would recommend to move the discussion there

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1087#issuecomment-663693457